# Segue causes model data to disappear

Tags: swift, segue, cs193p

I am trying to pass data from my model in my file, CalculatorBrain, to a ViewController through a segue. The var that I am trying to pass is designated as a PropertyList as shown below:

```
var program: PropertyList { // guaranteed to be PropertyList

    get {
        return opStack.map { $0.description }
    }

    set {
        if let opSymbols = newValue as? Array<String> {
            var newOpStack = [Op]()
            for opSymbol in opSymbols {
            if let op = knownOps[opSymbol] {
                newOpStack.append(op)
            } else if let operand = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(opSymbol)?.doubleValue {
                newOpStack.append(.Operand(operand))
            }
        }
            opStack = newOpStack
        }
    }
}
```

This is a multiple MVC project, and the override segue function is in a ViewController called "CalculatorViewController." The function tries to pass the data from the model to the ViewController known as "GraphingViewController" like this:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destination: UIViewController? = segue.destinationViewController
    if let navCon = destination as? UINavigationController {
        destination = navCon.visibleViewController
    }

    if let gvc = destination as? GraphingViewController {
            gvc.program = brain.program
    }
}
```

I set-up the variable program in my GraphingViewController as follows:

```
var program: AnyObject?
```

When I press the button that calls the segue, it does fire. What happens is that the data in brain.program gets copied into gvc.program. However, it is then LOST to the model. I don't know why this happens. **When I print the program out from the controller in the segue, I do see the program as it should be shown. However, when I print it anywhere after the segue, it has disappeared.**

Why would data, after the override segue function is called, be removed?

EDIT: This is the delegate function in the GraphingViewController. When I print out brain.program from here, it doesn't print out the full opStack.

```
  func graphForGraphView(xAxisValue: CGFloat, sender: GraphView) -> CGPoint? {
    print("BRAIN PROGRAM 2: \(brain.program)")
    brain.variableValues[brain.variableM] = 40.0

    if let yValue = brain.returnEvaluate() {
            print(yValue)
            print("The returned value is: \(yValue)")

        let point = CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: CGFloat(yValue))
            if !point.x.isNormal || !point.y.isNormal {
                return nil
            } else {
                return point
            }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: GraphingViewController program variable type is gonna be PropertyList not AnyObject

Comment: @Diogo Antunes That works, but strangely, I am now not getting the full value of brain.program being copied to gvc.program. Do you know what the reason could be? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by the full value? When you are getting brain.program you'r getter is iterating over the object and only returning the description :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The opStack has two values on it. The descriptions are string representations of each value. However, when I print out the returned descriptions, I only get the description for one of the two values.

Comment: For instance, if I print out brain.program, I would see ( desc1, desc2) but gvc.program only prints: ( desc2 )

Comment: That's strange. If you access brain.program inside the "prepareForSegue" it prints out two values?

Comment: If I access brain.program inside the segue, it prints out two values. When I print it out inside a delegate function in the GraphicalViewController, it only prints out the last value.

Comment: I've added the delegate function in edit above!

Comment: In your 'viewDidLoad' of the GraphingViewController if you access the program instance what is the value you get? I'm seeing a couple of red flags in your code but nothing that invalidates passing the full value of the 'program' variable